# Automatically selecting and deleting rows from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this code which is taking a number from H2 and by this number selecting X rows and print them. I can't figure it out how to delete the selection after printing them. If I do not clear H2 the code start some loop and printing non stop the selection. If I delete H2 number I will loose the selection and can't delete them.

If I can move my data from Sheet1 to Sheet3 (the whole column A) and to tell the code to select and print from there (when I eneter a number in Sheet1) and then to delete the printed rows it will be perfect.

Please help me with this one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim celltxt As String
Dim n As Range


'H2 is where the entry number is going to be
 Set n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")
  On Error GoTo Finalise
 'Select Column C and H2 number
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(n + 1, 1)).Select

celltxt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "") Then
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Range("H2") <> "" Then
 Selection.PrintOut
 Range("H2").ClearContents
 Selection.EntireRow.Delete
 End If
 Next ws

Else

End If
Finalise:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Select
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: You only have one loop that test if H2 is not blank. So yes, if you don't delete H2 it will be an endless loop. I've tested and cannot replicate your nondeletion issue. Perhaps moving the `clearcontents` to after the `entirerow.delete` row?

Comment: Do you know how to make the code to take the data from Sheet3 and delete the rows from there? I tried with Sheets("Sheet3").Activate and I changed few of Sheet1 to Worksheets("Sheet3") but couldn't figure it out. Doesn't want ot select the rows from Sheet3. :( 
I am not very good at coding and I was hoping someone with more skills to know few tricks and to manipulate the code. :) Then it won't be necessary to delete the row.

Comment: And ..yes, I removed the whole `Clearcontents` because it will delete the row no matter what so I do not need it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Even I couldn't manage to move the data to Sheet3 (if someone knows how I will be grateful), I managed to complete the code, but it takes the data from Column A1 and delete H2. The good news is that it delete the selection too.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim celltxt As String
Dim n As Range

'H2 is where the entry number is going to be
 Set n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1")
  On Error GoTo Finalise
 'Select Column C and H2 number
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(n + 1, 1)).Select

celltxt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "") Then
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Range("H2") <> "" Then
 Selection.PrintOut
 'Range("H2").ClearContents
 'ass.Delete Shift:=xlToUp
 Selection.EntireRow.Delete
 'Application.SendKeys ("{LEFT}")
 End If
 Next ws

Else

End If
Finalise:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Select
    Range("H2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Again if someone knows how to make a selection in other sheet and delete the rows from there and come back to H2 it will be awesome.

Thank you